# The screen fades when it is turned on, but nothing can be seen on it

Tags: laptop, display

[Photo of the monitor after start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD6wh.jpg)When the notebook (hp pavilion g6) is turned on, the screen fades, but nothing can be seen. I also changed the flex cable and nothing. Everything is running on the external screen, nothing can be seen on that laptop screen. In the appendix, I also send screenshots when I turn on the PC. Can there be a problem in the LCD panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine the problem is not related to system, you could check if it could boot into Safe Mode to check.
Depend on the picture you provided, if it works fine when you connect it to an external monitor, it could be related to the video cable from motherboard.
Get more information about this issue.
http://ccm.net/forum/affich-322927-screen-fades-white-after-black-on-boot-up
Also it could be related to the LCD panel. Depending on factors like the temperature, LCD panels can die quicker.